# How to increase disk space using non allocated memory from a deleted partition?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, memory

The partitions on my disk storage are disposed as follows:

A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F

I use Windows 10 on A and B. On C to F, Linux. The partition C is dedicated to Linux Swap. E operation system storage and F data storage.

D is a partition with non allocated space and E and F are two partitions that are full of data. I wish I could use the space from D to increase F.

Any simple solution to accomplish this?

I have tried from Linux using gparted and from windows using Disk management but both attempts failed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use some programs like Acton Acronis Disk Director to move the information from partition C to partition D, than format the partition C and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a more capable partition management software for this. I am not sure if the free version of Macrium Reflect can do it, but it looks promising. There are others out there for $$ and some other free ones. I used to use Easus' but it had problems, may be better now. GParted is OK for basic stuff, but this will probably require moving your E and F partitions down next to C and having the free space at the end of the drive and then expanding F using this now contiguous free space.